# Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement':

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If I upload a PDF or a picture to the form, I get the following error message when changing to another form field:

[image]

The upload function is done using the following JavaScript:

;(function($,window) {

```
$.plugin('OnacyUpload', {

    defaults: {
        fileUpload: '#register_license_upload',
        fileText: '.register-upload-file-text',
        registerContent: '.register--content.registration-upload-finished',
        registerLogin: '.register--login',
        sidebar: 'aside.sidebar-main',
        breadcrumb: 'nav.content--breadcrumb'
    },

    init: function() {
        var me = this;
        me._on(me.opts.fileUpload, 'change', $.proxy(me.onUploadChange, me));
        me._on(me.opts.fileText, 'click', $.proxy(me.fileTextClicked, me));


        if ( $(me.opts.registerContent).length ) {
            $(me.opts.registerLogin).remove();
            $(me.opts.sidebar).remove();
            $(me.opts.breadcrumb).remove();
        }

    },

    fileTextClicked: function() {
        $(me.opts.fileUpload).trigger('click');
    },

    onUploadChange: function(event) {

        var me        = this,
            $target   = $(event.target),
            $fileText = $(me.opts.fileText),
            value     = $target.val();

        if ( typeof value !== 'string' || value === '' ) {
            $fileText.html($fileText.attr('data-no-file-text'));
        }
        else {
            var list = value.replace(/\\/g, '/').split('/');
            $fileText.html(list[list.length-1]);
        }

    }

});

window.StateManager.addPlugin('body', 'OnacyUpload');
```

Here is the HTML Part:

```html
<div class="panel--body is--wide"> <input type="file" id="register_license_upload" name="register_license_upload" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf"> <label for="register_license_upload" class="btn is--secondary"> Datei aussuchen </label> <span class="register-upload-file-text" data-no-file-text="Datei wählen"> Datei wählen </span> </div>
```

Comment: Not seeing any attempt to set a value; still, can you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: The above is true, however I can see from the error that you're trying to set the value of an `input type="file"` element, which is not possible for security reasons. Whatever your goal is, you will need to find an alternative way of doing it

Comment: I´ve added the HTML Part